# binding hyper link buttons

Tags: windows-phone-8, hyperlink, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to bing the link of an Hyper link

```
<HyperlinkButton NavigateUri="{Binding link}" />
```

i also have a class with

```
public string link { get; set; }
```

my code behind is

```
protected async override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        if (DeviceNetworkInformation.IsNetworkAvailable)
        {
            base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
            string bass = "";
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                bass = await client.GetStringAsync("http://www.itisbarsanti.it/orario/");
            }
            HtmlDocument orari = new HtmlDocument();
            orari.LoadHtml(bass);

            List<listaorari> classi = new List<listaorari>();

            listaorari classe00 = new listaorari();
            classe00.Titolo = orari.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//a[@href='Classi/Classe0.html']").InnerText.Trim();
            classe00.link = "http://www.itisbarsanti.it/orario/Classi/Classe0.html";
            classi.Add(classe00);

            listaorari classe01 = new listaorari();
            classe01.Titolo = orari.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//a[@href='Classi/Classe1.html']").InnerText.Trim(); ;
            classe01.link = "http://www.itisbarsanti.it/orario/Classi/Classe1.html";
            classi.Add(classe01);

            lista_orari.ItemsSource = classi;
        }
        else
        {
            List<listaorari> orario0 = new List<listaorari>();
            listaorari orario = new listaorari();
            orario.Titolo = "No internet!";
            orario.link = "";
            orario0.Add(orario);
            lista_orari.ItemsSource = orario0;
        }
```

When i deploy the application  i don't see the hyper link buttons, but i can press them and when i press them the app crash!

HELPPPPPP!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see enough of your code to say for certain, but you have to have something that bubbles up changes to the 'link' property.   This means the ViewModel, or wherever the bound properties are kept, need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged (or similar) and raise property changed events when properties are modified (= set).

The app is probably crashing because the NavigateUrl property isn't set.

The code will look something like this:

```
// Create a class that implements INotifyPropertyChanged.
public class MyLinkVM: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _link;

    // Declare the PropertyChanged event.
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    // Create the property that will be the source of the binding.
    public string Link
    {
        get { return _link; }
        set
        {
            _link = value;
            // Call NotifyPropertyChanged when the source property 
            // is updated.
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Link");
        }
    }


    // NotifyPropertyChanged will raise the PropertyChanged event, 
    // passing the source property that is being updated.
    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, 
                new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```